# Hiding chat bot dialog in Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, chatbot

I'm trying to design a pop-up chat-bot in a Angular application. Right now I was able to code the popup dialog but couldn't able to hide it when clicking on the header. I'm trying to use Angular animations as well as Jquery but "slide toggle" is not working in Angular with Jquery hence I went for Angular animations.

Here is my corresponding typescript code

```
    <p>chat-popup works!</p>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Message box -->
    <div class="chat_box">
      <div class="chat_header">
        <!-- <img src="user.jpg" class="user_icon" /> -->
        <h4 class="username">Virtual agent</h4>
        <i class="fas fa-times close"></i>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div *ngIf="visible" class="message_content">
          <ng-container #messageList *ngFor="let message of messages | async">

              <div class="message" [ngClass]="{ 'from': message.sentBy === 'bot',
                                                'to':   message.sentBy === 'user' }">
                {{ message.content }}
              </div>

            </ng-container>
      </div>
      <div class="input_box">
        <input [(ngModel)]="formValue" (keyup.enter)="sendMessage()" placeholder="Your message here..." type="text">
        <button (click)="sendMessage()">se</button>
        <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my corresponding type script code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatService, Message } from '../chat.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { scan } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { trigger, transition, style, animate } from '@angular/animations';
declare var jQuery: any;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat-popup',
  templateUrl: './chat-popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat-popup.component.scss'],
  animations: [    trigger('slideInOut', [
    transition(':enter', [
      style({transform: 'translateY(-100%)'}),
      animate('200ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateY(0%)'}))
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      animate('200ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateY(-100%)'}))
    ])
  ])]
})
export class ChatPopupComponent implements OnInit {
  messages: Observable<Message[]>;
  formValue: string;
  visible = true;

  constructor(public chat: ChatService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Change detected');
    this.messages = this.chat.conversation.asObservable().pipe(scan((acc, val) => acc.concat(val))
    );
    // tslint:disable-next-line:only-arrow-functions
    (function($) {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:only-arrow-functions
      $(document).ready(function() {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:only-arrow-functions
        $('.chat_header').click(function() {
          console.log('Inside click');
          this.visible = false;
          console.log(this.visible);
          // $('.message_content').slideToggle('slow');
        });
      });
    })(jQuery);
  }

  sendMessage() {
    this.chat.converse(this.formValue);
    this.formValue = '';
  }

}
```

The click function is working and it is coming inside the Jquery code but it is not hiding the corresponding div where I gave the `ngIf*`. any help is appreciated

Comment: This might seem odd but what happens if you change your `visible` variable name to something else is it possible that you are using a reserved word

Comment: @DylanAnlezark, Tried it, it doesn't work